# wrong print of linked list c++

Tags: c++

Could you, please, explain me, why function "print" prints one same number infinitely in this code?

Apparently, linked list is constructed correctly, but while debugging step by step, it sticks on "print" function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

struct num {
    int n;
    num* next;};

void add (num*&head, int size) {
    num*newnode = new num;
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        newnode->n = rand()%100;
        newnode->next = head;
        head = newnode;}
}

void print (num*head) {
    num*temp = head;
    while (temp != 0) {
        cout << temp->n << endl;
        temp = temp ->next;}}

void del (num*&head) {
    num*temp = 0;
    while (head!=0){
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;}}

int main () {
srand ((unsigned int)time(0));
num*head = 0;
add (head, 10);
print (head);
del (head);
cin.get();
cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: The problem is in `add` function. You are not creating new nodes.Instead modifying the same node and pointing it to itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in add function. You are not creating new nodes.Instead modifying the same node and pointing it to itself.

Change like this

```
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        newnode = new num; //new node
        newnode->n = rand()%100;
        newnode->next = head;
        head = newnode;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a loop in your list in `add` function

```
newnode->next = head;
head = newnode;
```

So there is only 1 node and its `next` points to `head`, and `head` points to this node. If you move `num*newnode = new num;` inside the loop you'll fix this.